# How can i add interaction of two variables as a constraint in PuLP

Tags: python-3.x, optimization, pulp

I have an optimization problem in my hand and i want to add some constraints

```
maa_count = LpVariable("ManAtArmsCount", int(archer_count) - 1, None, LpInteger)
archer_count = LpVariable("ArcherCount", int(mangonel_count) + 1 , int(maa_count) - 1, LpInteger)
mangonel_count = LpVariable("MangonelCount", int(cavalry_count) + 1, int(archer_count) - 1, LpInteger)
cavalry_count = LpVariable("CavalryCount", 0, int(mangonel_count) - 1, LpInteger)
army_count = archer_count + maa_count + cavalry_count + mangonel_count
```

This code results in `TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'LpVariable'`

I tried to define variables with standart bounds and add a constraint with

```
prob += maa_count > archer_count > mangonel_count > cavalry_count
```

but this resulted in a type error stating that > operator cannot be used between lpvariables.

How can i fix this?

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Break up what you are trying to do.  You cannot reference a variable as a part of the construct of another variable.  The correct thing to do is to put upper/lower bounds (if it makes sense in the context of the problem) in the construction and then state any further relationships in constraints.  For instance if I want 2 integer variables and I want `y` to be greater than `x`, I just need to state that relationship in a constraint.  Also, do not cast things as `int()`...  just declare the variable as an integer type.  As such:

```
import pulp

prob = pulp.LpProblem('example', pulp.LpMinimize)

x = pulp.LpVariable('x', lowBound=0, cat=pulp.LpInteger)
y = pulp.LpVariable('y', lowBound=0, cat=pulp.LpInteger)

# state the relationship of the variables in a linear constraint...  And add it to the problem

prob += y >= x

print(prob)
```

#### Yields:

```
example:
MINIMIZE
None
SUBJECT TO
_C1: - x + y >= 0

VARIABLES
0 <= x Integer
0 <= y Integer
```

Comment: It doesn't allow to use comparators amongst LpVariable objects.

Comment: Ahhhh, sure it does.  I just did it above.  `y` and `x` are expressed in the constraint with a comparator.

Comment: ```
prob += -mangonel_count + cavalry_count < 0

```

results in

```
'<' not supported between instances of 'LpAffineExpression' and 'int'

```

Comment: most solvers do not support strict inequalities like `<`.  You should use `<=`.  And as you appear to be doing integer work, you could always get the same net result as a strict inequality by adding/subtracting 1 as needed...  `y >= x + 1`

Comment: If this answered your question, you should close out the issue by hitting the check mark next to the answer.